# Reopen question: Absconded from a reputed company after 7 days

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[I have absconded from a reputed company after 7 working days before signing any offer letter. What could be the consequences?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/116005/i-have-absconded-from-a-reputed-company-after-7-working-days-before-signing-any)

This was obviously not a duplicate, not legal advice that couldn't be handled by someone with simple HR level knowledge, and appears to have been closed for nothing more than a lack of knowledge of India.

Please reopen

Comment: This seem to be part of a pattern of questions being voted to be closed very hastily (look at the last 3-4 meta questions). Usually, the same users seem to be involved. Could there even be some possible malicious intent here?

Comment: @Time4Tea I don't think that the intent is malicious.  Some of us are more quick to close than others.  What defines a duplicate has been a hot button for a while.

Comment: ok, clearly you've been on the site longer than I have. It just seems that a lot of questions are getting closed lately by the same handful of people, for questionable reasons.

Comment: @Time4Tea yes, and I've been railing against that for some time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking for legal advice in in current form and any editing makes it a duplicate.  If you want the question reopened please edit it into a state that is on topic and not a duplicate

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings you feeling okay?

Answer (score 1):

Recent trend of close-voting notwithstanding, that question does seem to be more legal in nature than anything else.

The stated question, *What can I do to minimize my risk in this situation* is, despite [Monica Cellio's efforts](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/116005/7), still strongly legal in tone although it doesn't use the word *liability*. The accepted answer doesn't mention reprecautions with future employers and only addresses OP's legal risk.

It is closed because of a lack of knowledge of India, specifically, Indian law. For these reasons I would recommend it's shipped over to Law.SE.

Comment: It was answered by Masked Man, who is in India, gave what a lay person's knowledge to that issue would be.  As any workplace question that any lay person, up to someone with basic HR knowledge is on topic even if it has legal ramifications, the only thing left is India.  We have someone from India who can and has answered the question.  I'm loath to call something bigotry, but it appears to me that there is **some** reason behind all of this genuflecting.

Comment: @RichardU I think it's because we've trained ourselves to be averse to legal-sounding questions. Decades of <IANAL></IANAL> does take its toll

Comment: *"The accepted answer doesn't mention reprecautions with future employers and only addresses OP's legal risk."* The accepted answer also doesn't mention what happens if a war breaks out between India and China. Why? Because that's not relevant to the question. Same as "precautions with future employers" because that is neither asked for nor necessary. If there is absolutely no risk for the OP and he hasn't asked for it, I don't see why it has to be explicitly stated.

Comment: *"It is closed because of a lack of knowledge of India, specifically, Indian law."* That makes no sense. The question has already been answered based on knowledge of Indian law, and it even explicitly mentions what Indian courts would do with such a legal case.

Comment: @MaskedMan I'm glad you agree with my main point - that the question (and answer) are basically about law. The reason for closing (my 3rd paragraph) is not a justification, but an observation; it is answered (by one person) in terms of Indian law, but closed (by many) due to lack of knowledge on the subject, and, I posit, due to unwillingness to deal with the subject of law.

Comment: @rath It is a legal question that can be answered by a competent HR. I don't need to be a lawyer to know that stealing company property is illegal, for example. If people lack knowledge on the subject, they should leave it for someone who has the knowledge.